# What bracha to make if ate mezonos and grapes but only bentched for mezonos?

Tags: halacha, blessing, fruits

Do we say Al Hamichiya again for the grapes or because sofek bracha lehakel, we omit the one for the grapes?

Comment: 1) Al hamichya is on mezonos; you mean meein shalosh 2) sofek bracha lehakel is when you have a doubt. There's no doubt here...

Comment: Grapes are one of the seven species and therefore the corresponding bracha achrona is al ha eitz...b'diavad one section of mayin shalosh covers the other sections so you have fulfilled your obligation

Answer (score 3):

From Star K website;

> If a person ate grapes and, instead of reciting “ al ha’eitz” throughout the bracha said “ al hagefen”, he is  yotzeh.3  [If he ate grapes and drank wine, but recited only “ al hagefen” without specific intent for the grapes that he ate, he must recite a separate  brocha acharona for the grapes.4

> (ii)                If a person drank wine and, instead of reciting “ al hagefen” throughout the  brocha said “ al hamichya” or “ al ha’eitz”, he is still  yotzei.5   [If he drank wine and also ate a  mezonos item or one of the  shivas  haminim, but recited only “ al hamichya” or “ al ha’eitz” without having specific intent for the wine, he must recite another  brocha acharona for the wine.6

> (iii)               If a person ate dates and, instead of reciting “ al ha’eitz” throughout the brocha said “ al hamichya”, he is still  yotzei.7  [If he ate dates and a mezonos item, but recited only “ al hamichya” without specific intent for the dates, he must recite another  brocha acharona for the dates.8

> (iv)              Other than the three cases noted above, if a person inserted the wrong phrase throughout the  brocha, he is not  yotzei and must repeat the brocha correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In an appropriate shiur it was explained that *al hamichyah* applies only to mezonos and *al hagefen* only to wine and *al haetz* only to the specific fruits. Thus, if one says one of them, the others can be said separately. If one does remember, then they are included in the *maein shalosh* at the appropriate location (such as *al Hamichyah veal hagefen*).